# How do you run a javascript outside of the localhost directory with requirejs?

Tags: javascript, html, requirejs, localhost, global-variables

I am working with a multi directory program that relies on requirejs, and I'm new to this structure and to javascript in general.

I have a html file that is in a localhost and I need to get it to access a variable that is stored in a javascript file outside of that localhost. I've tried creating a global variable, but the javascript file storing the variable isn't run, so the value is never set and the global variable is null.
The file structure is:

- lib

  - direc

    - config

      - script1.js
    - src

      - public

        - script2.js
        - index.html

I need to run script1 from index and when I use the format below I get a 404 error.

```html
<script src ="../../config/script1.js"></script>
```

The variable I need to pass is a string that was parsed by script1.js from a kaml file, although I'm not sure if it's parsed correctly since this script doesn't seem to be running since it isn't called from the html. Also, the localhost seems to be centered at the public folder and the 404 error indicates that it is looking for script1 at the url "localhost/config/script1.js".  Like I said I'm new to javascript and to node.js, but I've looked for this answer and have yet to find something that works with my program.

Comment: I think we're mixing a few concepts here. If you're referencing this script in a HTML file, you're probably not running node.js, but javascript in a browser environment. Tell us more of your setup.

Comment: Hi, frankly I don't know much more about the setup.  I've just been given this small task in a larger project.  I think saying node.js was a mistake though.  I meant that it uses requirejs, sorry I will edit appropriately.

Comment: Unless something is serving the file, you won't be able to access it outside of your source directory, even with require.js. You could server-side with Node, but not from the client-side as far as I know.

Comment: Your browser will not be able to reach that file unless you do at least 1 of two things: move it to the public folder, or make the config folder accessible to the web, neither of which are a good idea if it is storing sensitive information.

Comment: Kevin, would there be a way for me to transfer the variable into script2.js? Script2 is accessible to the browser since it is in the public folder, which would also solve my problem